# Codeigniter: instantiate_class function()

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I read the source of Codeigniter, I found a function located in file:system/codeigniter/comm.php like that:

```
/**
* Instantiate Class
*
* Returns a new class object by reference, used by load_class() and the DB class.
* Required to retain PHP 4 compatibility and also not make PHP 5.3 cry.
*
* Use: $obj =& instantiate_class(new Foo());
*/
function &instantiate_class(&$class_object)
{
    return $class_object;
}
```

I can't undestand it well, and I need more details about the compatibility things. Thanks.

update: Codeigniter version is 1.7.2

Comment: What version of CI is that? Starting from V 2 on, they dropped compatibility with PHP4 (at last!), so you're better off using those versions, which are also safer and less buggy

Comment: Read DocComment: "Required to retain PHP 4 compatibility and also not make PHP 5.3 cry"

Comment: @Damien Pirsy: That's a myth, by fact CI V 2 on contains a lot of PHP 4 code (a lot of PHP 4 work-around code in fact).

Comment: @Damien Pirsy: Yes, but the project use Codeigniter 1.7.2, so I must start from 1.7.2.

Comment: @hakre I didn't checked all source files, I just assumed they told the truth, but I've seen quite "old" code styles, but at least they started moving on the right direction. They're still far from Kohana, Yii or Lithium, though

Comment: @hakre: `php > error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
php > $a = & new stdClass;

Strict standards: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in php shell code on line 1`. I think the function should bypass the strict warning in 5.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function and it's example use in question is totally bogus:

```
$obj =& instantiate_class(new Foo());
```

That's the same as writing:

```
$obj =& new Foo();
```

Which is the way that needed to be done in PHP 4.

Since PHP 5, you can just write:

```
$obj = new Foo();
```

as you might know.

Actually, as you, I do not see any use of the function just for the sole purpose that it's superflous. It might have had some need in the past (when it had some other definition). I can only assume about it's existance, most likely that the developer had problems to understand [references/aliasing in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) which is commonly not well understood.

**Edit:** As KingCrunch pointed out, there is a need for this function if you would like to glue PHP 4 with PHP 5.3 code, because it will prevent strict standards warnings in PHP 5.3. So instead of the PHP 4 (potentially needed)

```
$obj =& new Foo();
```

This must be written as

```
$obj =& instantiate_class(new Foo());
```

Which hides away the "Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated" warning and allows to code in a PHP 4 style for a PHP 5.3 environment.

Hope this helps you with your [software archaeology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_archaeology).

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above: `$obj =& new Foo;` emits a `strict`-warning in 5.3. I think, thats what they mean with "crying"

Comment: That means the function exists to glue together PHP 4 and PHP 5.3 code, thanks KingCrunch, that explains it.